# What is the difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf and Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, blazor, blazor-desktop

I am currently trying to finish my very first blazor desktop app using WPF. The only thing I'm missing is the drag behaviour with a WindowStyle="none" WPF MainWindow.
I found the following git repo: https://github.com/AndrewBabbitt97/BlazorDesktop/

The author has found a way for dragging the window from i.e. a navbar but he uses Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf and I started my project using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf like this https://github.com/edandersen/blazor-desktop-crossplatform-sample/tree/master/src/BlazorWpfApp. Can someone explain the difference and when I should use what?

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked for some time. However, I recently came across it because I was also toying with the idea of looking for an alternative to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf" due to this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18908 unresolved issue.

To answer the question very briefly:
**Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf** is used for embedding web content in WPF applications, leveraging the Microsoft Edge Chromium-based rendering engine for displaying web content.
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf** is used for *hosting Blazor WebAssembly* applications in WPF, allowing developers to build desktop applications with a web-based UI using Blazor and .NET.

If a WPF Blazor Blazor app is to be created with WebAssembly, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf is the right component. If only server-side rendering is used, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf can be used.